# Using CGContext with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to use [CGContext](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext) while using SwiftUI View. How to get current CGContext?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you don't use Core Graphics inside of SwiftUI. However, if you have Core Graphics code that you want to use, it's fairly straightforward. You need to wrap a UIView and draw in there.

To include a UIView in a SwiftUI view hierarchy, use [UIViewRepresentable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable). You can then include your Core Graphics code in `drawRect` as usual, and embed that in your SwiftUI.

Apple provides a tutorial on this in [Interfacing with UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit).

Note that SwiftUI itself doesn't expose a Core Graphics context. It's a declarative language that describes the view hierachy. You don't have access to the "actual" drawing objects. (And the actual drawing objects aren't promised to use CGContext internally, though most and possibly all do.)

Answer (score 2):

### From `iOS 15`

Apple introduced new SwiftUI view named [`Canvas`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/canvas) which provide [`GraphicsContext`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/graphicscontext) in closure.

[`GraphicsContext`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/graphicscontext) is SwiftUI equivalent of `CGContext`. You can even use existing drawing code that relies on Core Graphics primitives through the method named [`withCGContext(content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/graphicscontext/withcgcontext(content:))